# guardar valores de una consulta en una clase, mediante jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, sql, spring-boot, jdbc

buenas tardes tengo una consulta, como podría guardar los valores de una consulta en un modelo o clase mediante jdbctemplate.

este es mi codigo:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/formobligatorio/{pidm}" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<FormPerson> grupoCodf(@PathVariable Long pidm) {
      int codf = 0;
      LinkedList<Integer> codFormsOblig = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> codfoblig = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String query=" select p.codigo_uzgtformularios from UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p,UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS f where p.spriden_pidm =" + pidm + "and p.codigo_uzgtformularios = f.codigo_uzgtformularios and (  p.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='N' or f.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='S' or f.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado ='M' )  ORDER BY codigo_UZGTFORMULARIOS ASC";
        codfoblig = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query,Integer.class);
        for (int u = 0; u < codfoblig.size(); u++) {
            codf = codfoblig.get(u);
            codFormsOblig.add(codf);
        }
        System.out.println("codFormsOblig "+codFormsOblig);
```

// Aqui es mi problema el codFormsOblig tiene 2 valores, x lo tanto el query de abajo se va a ejecutar 2 veces con resultados distintos, y esos 2 resultados necesito guardarlo en mi modelo o clase FormPerson.

```
     for (int u = 0; u < codFormsOblig.size(); u++) {
String query1="SELECT CODIGO_UZGTFORMULARIOS, UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO FROM UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS where UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO = 1 AND codigo_uzgtFormularios=" + codFormsOblig.get(u) + " AND UZGTFORMULARIOS_EO = '0' ORDER BY codigo_UZGTFORMULARIOS ASC";
                } 
    //No sé que tipo de jdbctemplate utilizar, queryforobject, queryforlist o algun otro que me permita //guardar los resultados del select;
      List<FormPerson> cod = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query1, FormPerson.class);     

                    return cod;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas tardes lo primero que debes hacer es crear un RowMapper, por ejemplo

```
   public class ClaimTrackingRecord implements RowMapper<ClaimTrackingRecord> {

    private String taskDate;

    public String getTaskDate() {
        return taskDate;
    }

    public void setTaskDate(String taskDate) {
        this.taskDate = taskDate;
    }

    @Override
    public ClaimTrackingRecord mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        ClaimTrackingRecord claimTrackingRecord = new ClaimTrackingRecord();
        claimTrackingRecord.setTaskDate(rs.getString("fecha_tarea"));
        return claimTrackingRecord;
    }

    }
```

lo mas importante es sobreescribir el metodo mapRow ya aqui es donde conviertes tu ResultSet en el objecto en tu caso FormPerson.

Luego en tu Repository o en el lugar donde estes usando tu jdbcTemplate, instancias tu mapper, por ejemplo

```
  @Repository
public class CustomerCareRepositoryImpl implements CustomerCareRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private final RowMapper<ClaimTrackingRecord> claimTrackingRecordMapper;

    public CustomerCareRepositoryImpl() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        claimTrackingRecordMapper = ClaimTrackingRecord.class.newInstance();
    }

    }
```

y finalmente ejecutas la consulta, por ejemplo

```
    @Override
public List<ClaimTrackingRecord> getRecordsClaimTrackingByClaimNumber(Long claimNumber) {
    String query = "select to_char(fecha_tarea_realizada,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM PM') fecha_tarea from tb_seguimiento_reclamos where id_corr_reclamo = ? order by id_corr_seguimiento_reclamos desc";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, claimTrackingRecordMapper, claimNumber);
}
```

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.